# Getting .name from a user Object in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I first do this in my script

```
async def tictactoe(ctx, player2: discord.Member):
    player1 = ctx.author.name
    
    num = random.randint(1, 2)
    if num == 1:
        turn = player1
    elif num == 2:
        turn = player2
```

And later

```
if turn == ctx.message.author.name:
```

However, I cannot seem to find a way to get the name to properly compare player1 and player2 and it will only accept player 1's turns and not recognize player 2. I know its with getting player 2's name I just can't find how to do it.

Comment: I've never seen anyone compare users by name, typically it's by ID or by comparison (`ctx.author == player2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Łukasz Kwieciński's comment is correct, usually, people compare discord IDs as they are generally static, whereas names can change often.

If you want to get player2s name, then `player2.name` should work just fine.
[docs.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.name)
From there you can compare your two variables as you need.

```
async def tictactoe(ctx, player2: discord.Member):
    player1 = ctx.author.name
    
    player2 = player2.name
    
    num = random.randint(1, 2)
    if num == 1:
        turn = player1
    elif num == 2:
        turn = player2


    if turn == player2:
        #do player2 stuff
```